# Why EF Core navigation properties doesnt fill?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I face a problem with below code

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var mainPageViewModel = new MainPageViewModel()
        {
            Walls = await _unitOfWork.Walls.GetAllAsync(),
            PopularStoreProducts = await Context.Set<StoreProduct>().Include(sp => sp.Product).Include(sp => sp.Store).ToListAsync(),
            Reviews = await _unitOfWork.Reviews.GetAllWithIncludeAsync()
        };
        var cartItems = await Context.Set<CartItem>().Include(ci => ci.StoreProduct).ThenInclude(sp => sp.Product)
            .Include(ci => ci.StoreProduct).ThenInclude(sp => sp.Store).ToListAsync(); ;

        return View(mainPageViewModel);
    }
```

When I trace above code, cartItems.StoreProduct won't be null but an empty StoreProduct.

Everything will be fine when I remove this line:

```
PopularStoreProducts = await Context.Set<StoreProduct>().Include(sp => sp.Product).Include(sp => sp.Store).ToListAsync(),
```

My question is that why navigation properties sets empty when I already read that navigation properties in their one's queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are not initializing the reference navigation property `CarItem.StoreProduct` to `new StoreProduct()`

Comment: Is this your *exact* code? Do you have any other code in-between that does something like empty out unwanted details from mainPageViewModel.PopularStoreProducts? (the code does nothing with cartItems) When you call the EF DbContext to fetch the PopularStoreProducts it loads references to those entities. A later call against those tables would return those same references where available rather than going to the Database to fetch them again.